# search for category in reference document in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

**category schema**

```
const CategorySchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    catName: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

**Product Schema**

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    brand: { type: String, required: true },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    categories: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category" },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

**
This is my code to search for category name while knowing that the data stored in my product model is a reference Id from category model**

```
const qCategory = req.query.category;

else if (qCategory) {
      products = await Product.find({
        categories: {
          catName: qCategory
        }
      }).populate("categories");
    }
```

I have tried whatever I know, Please help me out.

I need to search by categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the id of the category first, then use this id to query the products:

```
const qCategory = req.query.category;    

const category = await Category.findOne({ catName: qCategory });

if (category) {
    products = await Product.find({ categories: category._id }).populate("categories");
}
```

Also I think you wanna change the name to singular category, because  currently it allows to store just one.

If you want to store multiple you need to change for this:

```
categories: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category" }],
```

Comment: This is my search functionality, from a search box. It is able to search in a brand and title but i need it to search in category as well, example: if someone types sunglasses. so how do you suggest me to tackle this.

`router.get("/search/:key", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let products = await Product.find({
      $or: [
        { title: { $regex: req.params.key, $options: "i" } },
        { brand: { $regex: req.params.key, $options: "i" } },
        { categories: { $regex: req.params.key, $options: "i" } }
      ]
    });`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
router.get("/search/:key", async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const category = await Category.findOne({ catName: req.params.key });

        let products = await Product.find({
            $or: [
                { title: { $regex: req.params.key, $options: "i" } },
                { brand: { $regex: req.params.key, $options: "i" } },
                { categories: category?._id }
            ]
        });
    } catch {

    }
});
```

Comment: Hey paulo can you please take a look at this and guide me to a solution. Thank you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76421719/reviews-about-products-in-express

Comment: hey Paulo, if you have any idea where I'm wrong in this, please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76914612/unable-to-upload-image-and-save-in-mongo