# Reviews about products in Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This is my Schema for Review

```
review: [
      {
        user: { type: Number },
        name: { type: String },
        comment: { type: String }
      }
    ]
```

This is a very simple code although i'll also need to put a condition to check if user has already entered review about the same product, if he has then just update his old review with new one.

```
router.post("/review", verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { comment, productId } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findById({ _id: req.user.id });
    const review = {
      user: req.user.id,
      name: user.username,
      comment
    };
    const product = await Product.findById(productId);
    product.review.push(review);
    await product.save();
    res.status(200).json(product);
```

This seems to give me cast problems plus validation errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you provided that's the help I can give. The review user needs to be an object id not a number, and I am always removing the review of the user in case there is one, no need to check if there is one to remove, just remove it and add the new. Try it and let me know how did it go.

```
    review = [
        {
            user: { type: ObjectId }, // cannot be number, needs to be object Id
            name: { type: String },
            comment: { type: String }
        }
    ]


app.post("/review", verifyTokenAndAuthorization, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { comment, productId } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findById({ _id: req.user.id });
        const review = {
            user: req.user.id,
            name: user.username,
            comment
        };

        const product = await Product.findById(productId);

        product.review = product.review.filter(rev => rev.user !== user._id); // removes the current review if there is one

        product.review.push(review);
        await product.save();
        res.status(200).json(product);
    }
    catch {
        res.status(500).json("Problem");
    }
});
```

Comment: Alright. Its working. thank you again. is there anyway to connect with you on linkedin or something. I'd want to learn from you.